# greater than or equal java for loop nested

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

If I only put `y>x; y--;` in the inner loop it prints `5432` but when I put `y>=x; y--;` in the inner loop it prints `54321`. What happened there?

What does `y>=x; y--;` mean? It means `y` is greater than or equal to `x` right? But why did it print `54321`?

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) {


        int x;
        int y;


            for(x=1; x<=5; x++){
                for(y=5; y>=x; y--){

                    System.out.print(y);
                }

                System.out.println();
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: `y>=x` means "y is greater than or equal to x". It printed 54321 because that's what you told it to do.

Comment: Turn on your debugger, it's the fastest way to see it for yourself and understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if y > x and x is 1 then 1 will not be included in you printed list as y will never be less then x which is 1. When you made it = x then you allowed 1 to be allowed by y